# How to add for the TBitmapImage the OnClick notify event

Tags: inno-setup

I'm looking for a way to add the OnClick notify event to the TBitmapImage object.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

grate news on the 5.4.0 (2010-10-31) inno-setup:
"TBitmapImage: Added new OnClick and OnDblClick properties. See the CodeClasses.iss example script for an example" .Hurray!!

Answer (score 0):

Well, according to the Pascal Scripting documentation that ships with InnoSetup 5, `TBitmapImage` does not have an `OnClick` event, so you can not "listen" to that event.